# How do I properly authenticate Google Account for YouTube v3 Google APIs for .NET

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've searched all around, and the documentation on this is out of date (the page located here show examples of earlier versions of the Google .net apis: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)

I'm trying to create an application for resumable uploads to YouTube. I have my application registered on the Google APIs console and have my client secrets and client id. This is the approach I am using to authenticate:

```
UserCredential credential;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "[my_username]", CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("YouTube.ListMyLibrary"));
}
```

The process hangs on the await call. The client_secrets.json file is loading just fine (tested this separately). When the AuthorizeAsync is called, however, I do get the following output before it hangs:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I have absolutely no clue what files it is looking for. I have looked at several other samples and I'm just at a complete loss on how to do this. There seems to be no clear way to authenticate with the Youtube v3 api.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check if other samples from our samples repository don't work for you as well (You can check our Books sample for example https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2FBooks.ListMyLibrary). Also please verify that the following patch was already installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556

Comment: It turns out that I was using .NET Framework 4.5 instead of 4 which was causing it to break. Starting fresh with .NET 4 solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You can work with .NET 4.5 OR .NET 4.0. But it's not recommended to change the target framework after you already installed all the NuGet dependencies.

Comment: I started a new project with .NET 4 rather than change the framework in the first project. It clearly does not work in .NET 4.5, at least in Visual Studio 2012. Probably should be looked at, I know it's still a beta.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work on .NET 4.5? If you start a new project and install the latest NuGet version of Google.Apis.Youtube.v3  and then copy the core above, you are getting that error? I'm not aware that it doesn't work on .NET 4.5. Maybe you need to install some patch \ service pack. check if you have the latest version of 4.5, if not update it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, with 4.5 I am getting the errors above. I would love to troubleshoot it for you guys and possibly file a bug report but right now I'm on a tight deadline and will be moving forward with .NET 4 for the time being. I appreciate your timely responses, though. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to use our issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list. It's weird because running a .NET 4.5 application using the library WORKS IN MY MACHINE :) I would be happy to figure out what is the reason it doesn't work for you. THANKS

Comment: I'm having the same problem with .NET 4.5. It seems to start an infinite loop when  AuthorizeAsync is called.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open,
                                 FileAccess.Read))  {
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] {YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload  },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2FTasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2

refer this link...it worked for me..

just add one json file with your client id and client secret like :

{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "your client id"
    "client_secret": "your client secret"
  }
}

```
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2.client_secrets.json"))
        {
            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Tasks.ASP.NET.Sample.Store"),
                ClientSecretsStream = stream,
                Scopes = new[] { TasksService.Scope.TasksReadonly }
            });
        }

        var uri = Request.Url.ToString();
        var code = Request["code"];
        if (code != null)
        {
            var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId, code,
                uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")), CancellationToken.None).Result;

            // Extract the right state.
            var oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(
                flow.DataStore, UserId, Request["state"]).Result;
            Response.Redirect(oauthState);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId,
                CancellationToken.None).Result;
            if (result.RedirectUri != null)
            {
                // Redirect the user to the authorization server.
                Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri);
            }
            else
            {
                // The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.
                service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApplicationName = "Tasks API Sample",
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential
                });
            }
        }
```